# Trouble with intuition of convergence in measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble trying to "read" what exactly convergence in measure is meaning. Specifically, I'm working on showing $f_n = n^{-1/p}1_{[0,n]}$ converges in measure to $0$ on   $(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{B}, m)$ where $m$ is the labesgue measure.

So I'd like to show $\lim_{n->\infty} m(\{x \in \mathbb{R} : |n^{-1/p}1_{[0,n]}| \geq \alpha\})=0$, $\forall \alpha>0$

I'd like to just examine the measure of the set in mind, it's saying to look at the measure of the set of the x in $\mathbb{R}$ such that the condition applies. I was thinking that the set could just be empty if $x$ isn't in $[0,n]$, and otherwise the measure of the set would just be $n(n^{-1/p})$. In either case, the measure of the set goes to $0$. Is this mode of thinking correct, or am I seeing it wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, examining the measure is a good approach. If $\alpha\gt 0$ is fixed, we have to find a bound for 
$$\lambda\{x\in\mathbb R,\chi_{(0,n)}\geqslant \alpha^p\cdot n\}.$$

This measure is $0$ when $\alpha^p\cdot n\gt 1$.

Notice that the bound of this measure by $n$ doesn't allow us to conclude.

They are at least two  reasons for which a sequence of functions converges to $0$ in measure:

- the measure of the support of $f_n$ goes to $0$;
- the measure of the support is very large, but the values taken on it are small enough.

Comment: So expanding on when the measure is $0$, we need to choose $N$ so that $1 < N \alpha^{p}$ ? So that our measure goes to $0$, $\forall n \geq N$

Comment: Yes, exactly. ${}{}$